# Information compression for variable input size

Tags: machine-learning, autoencoder, feature-reduction

Is there a way to compress information of a variable input size?

Autoencoder requires standardized input sizes. Although I can add masks on the cost function and add dummy features to standardize input/output size, I am hesitant with the potential drawbacks.

The input structures I am interested in are graphs and images. If input sizes and shapes vary too much, padding, resizing and rescaling do not work.